# ImportError: No module named moves

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, six

**Versions**

- **Python** : 2.7.14
- **six** : 1.9.0 & 1.11.0(*tried on both*)
- **OS** : mac(10.13.3) & ubuntu(16.04) [*tried on both*]

**Error**

> from six.moves import http_client
>   ImportError: No module named moves

**Description**

In flask application which is running on google app engine while running it on local system using `dev_appserver.py` getting above error while importing `from six.moves import http_client`

**What I have tried**

After importing six have tried `dir(six)` which shows that `moves` is there in list but it's not able to import it which is very strange.

Output of `six.__version__`: 1.11.0

Output if dir(six)

> ['/opt/tribes-backend', '/opt/tribes-backend/lib1', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/ssl-2.7.11', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/grpcio-1.0.0', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/six-1.9.0', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/protobuf-3.0.0', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/enum-0.9.23', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/futures-3.0.5', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-36.6.0', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/pytz-2017.2', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.1.1', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/werkzeug-0.11.10', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/yaml-3.10', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/enum', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/concurrent/concurrent', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google', '/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google']
>   ['BytesIO', 'Iterator', 'MAXSIZE', 'Module_six_moves_urllib', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_error', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_request', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_response', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_robotparser', 'MovedAttribute', 'MovedModule', 'PY2', 'PY3', 'StringIO', '_LazyDescr', '_LazyModule', '_MovedItems', '_SixMetaPathImporter', '**author**', '**builtins**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**version**', '_add_doc', '_assertCountEqual', '_assertRaisesRegex', '_assertRegex', '_func_closure', '_func_code', '_func_defaults', '_func_globals', '_import_module', '_importer', '_meth_func', '_meth_self', '_moved_attributes', '_print', '_urllib_error_moved_attributes', '_urllib_parse_moved_attributes', '_urllib_request_moved_attributes', '_urllib_response_moved_attributes', '_urllib_robotparser_moved_attributes', 'absolute_import', 'add_metaclass', 'add_move', 'advance_iterator', 'assertCountEqual', 'assertRaisesRegex', 'assertRegex', 'b', 'binary_type', 'byte2int', 'callable', 'class_types', 'create_bound_method', 'exec_', 'functools', 'get_function_closure', 'get_function_code', 'get_function_defaults', 'get_function_globals', 'get_method_function', 'get_method_self', 'get_unbound_function', 'indexbytes', 'int2byte', 'integer_types', 'iterbytes', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'iterlists', 'itertools', 'itervalues', 'moves', 'next', 'operator', 'print_', 'python_2_unicode_compatible', 'raise_from', 'remove_move', 'reraise', 'string_types', 'sys', 'text_type', 'types', 'u', 'unichr', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues', 'with_metaclass', 'wraps'].

As it can be seen from above output `moves` inside `six` still giving error while importing it.

Spent a lot of time on this and no solution till now any help would be greatly appreciated here. :(

**UPDATE1**

Error stacktrace :-

```
 from google.cloud.datastore import helpers
 File "/opt/tribes-backend/denv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/helpers.py", line 27, in <module>
 from google.cloud._helpers import _datetime_to_pb_timestamp
 File "/opt/tribes-backend/denv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 30, in <module>
 from six.moves import http_client
 ImportError: No module named moves
```

Comment: Here's how I resolved this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51616840/901444

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on follow up with google support team have figured out that communicating with `datastore` using `google-cloud-datastore` is deprecated 
instead using `ndb` for communicating datastore is the way to go.

Updated documentation stating deprecation using client datastore library is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/#connecting_to_datastore_name_short_with_app_engine)

Documentation to getting started with **ndb client library** in python is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries)

Answer (score 5):

For me the issue was resolved by following it on https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb/issues/249

andrewsg commented 11 days ago:

> I think we've identified an issue with devappserver related to the six library specifically. Could you please try a workaround? Add the line: `import six; reload(six)` to the top of your app, before NDB is loaded and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases if you want to use some python pure libraries, like six, available in your applications you will need to use third-party libraries. 
Follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27), to add a third-party library, until the command `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`. In your requirements.txt file just add `six==1.11.0`.
It solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks @gonçalo-albino sorry forgot to put this in question but have already tried it with no luck :(

Comment: Have you tried using the GAE-provided six lib by requesting it in the libraries section of your app.yaml file, like is showed here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime @vinitpayal

Comment: yes @gonçalo-albino tried with it also and in fact tried with six1.9.0(as it was suggested at [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27)) and six1.11.0 both but none of them helped

Comment: After you add the library six to your app.yaml file are you getting the same error message? @vinitpayal

Comment: Yes @gonçalo-albino

Comment: Have you tried to create a isolated python environment with virtualenv[http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ ]?  This way you can provide the exact package version that you need for your project. Try to create a virtualenv environment, activate it and then follow this documentation[https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library ] for copying a third-party library.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @gonçalo-albino but actually I am already in virtualenvironment

Comment: I'm in the Google Cloud Platform support team and I saw that you have filed a support ticket. May you share the information when you get the resolution for the issue? Thanks

Comment: Have got a response from cloud support team saying `the app engine standard runtime uses ndb client library to access datastore. You can't use the Cloud Datastore client library with Python applications in app engine stnadard environment.` which actually solved my problem

Comment: @vinitpayal May I ask you to post the comment as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @gonçalo-albino you were really helpful in the process of reaching to a solution