# Google API Python Client: "from six.moves import zip ImportError: No module named moves"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I am trying to use the Google Sheets API in my Python 2.7 code using the googleapiclient but I get the following error: "from six.moves import zip
ImportError: No module named moves ".

I am using Python 2.7.10 on Mac.

My programme is built using Webapp2, deployed on Google AppEngine and is connected to Google Datastore.

I am using Google's best practice for using third party libraries, using `requirements.txt`, `lib/` and `appengine_config.py`, described here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library

I have tried listing six as a bundled library in my `app.yaml`

I have tried playing around with different versions of `six` and `google-api-python-client`

I have tried the solutions suggest here:

1) [ImportError: No module named moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188151/importerror-no-module-named-moves)

2) [Google App Engine: from six.moves import http_client no module named moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768023/google-app-engine-from-six-moves-import-http-client-no-module-named-moves/51616840#51616840)

Things to note:

I can make a successful Google Sheets API call from my Python shell.

I tried a different, clunkier approach; downloading `google-api-client-gae-1.2.zip` from https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-python-client/downloads and unzipping it in my root directory. This required importing `apiclient` into my code instead of `googleapiclient` and whilst it did not have any trouble importing six.moves, it threw missing API Key errors. I believe these errors would not be an issue if I solve the six.moves import error above as I have a `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable set which the `google_api_python_client` would pick up on.

My code:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

class SpreadsheetProcessor:

    def __init__(self, spreadsheet_id, range_):
        service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4')
        request = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_)
        response = request.execute()
        self.results = [value[0] for value in response['values']]
```

My pip freeze:

```
autopep8==1.4.3
cachetools==3.0.0
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
enum34==1.1.6
fancycompleter==0.8
futures==3.2.0
google-api-core==1.7.0
google-api-python-client==1.7.7
google-auth==1.6.2
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-cloud-core==0.29.1
google-cloud-datastore==1.7.3
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.6
grpcio==1.18.0
httplib2==0.12.0
idna==2.8
linecache2==1.0.0
pdbpp==0.9.3
protobuf==3.6.1
pyasn1==0.4.5
pyasn1-modules==0.2.3
pycodestyle==2.4.0
Pygments==2.3.1
pyrepl==0.8.4
pytz==2018.9
requests==2.21.0
rsa==4.0
six==1.12.0
traceback2==1.4.0
uritemplate==3.0.0
uritemplate.py==3.0.2
urllib3==1.24.1
wmctrl==0.3
```

My full stack trace:

```
ERROR    2019-01-20 11:52:23,705 wsgi.py:263]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/muzzialdean/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/muzzialdean/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/muzzialdean/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/muzzialdean/Muzzi/tech-tests/ghostr/ghostr.py", line 3, in <module>
    from models import Ghost, GhostDatabase
  File "/Users/muzzialdean/Muzzi/tech-tests/ghostr/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from googleapiclient import discovery
  File "/Users/muzzialdean/Muzzi/tech-tests/ghostr/lib/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 21, in <module>
    from six.moves import zip
ImportError: No module named moves
INFO     2019-01-20 11:52:23,715 module.py:861] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0):

The `six` module is one of the [built-in third party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) in the App Engine Python 2.7 runtime. The only available version is `1.9.0`, but this version has the `six.moves` submodule:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 13 2018, 17:12:41)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from six.moves import zip
>>> import six
>>> six.__version__
'1.9.0'
```

It seems like you might have an old version of `six` in your `lib` directory, or perhaps a file in your project named `six.py`?