# Can Google Cloud Endpoints work with Text To Speech?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to keep my Google Cloud project centered around App Engine (GAE) Standard Environment by running a UI in GAE Python 2.7 and then deploying an OpenAPI to Cloud Endpoints which also uses Python 2.7.  I want my API to be able to check Google Cloud Storage (GCS) for a file, and then if it doesn't exist, fetch an Entity from Datastore, process some data with Text-
to-Speech, and then save resulting mp3 to GCS.

Under Python 2.7, [I need to use the old (2015)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) `cloudstorage` client library, `google-endpoints`, `google-endpoints-api-management` and `google-cloud-texttospeech` modules, all in my `./lib` folder.

With these modules installed, I can run the ["echo" demo project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo) without problem.  This indicates that there are no dependency version conflicts.  However, when trying to use `texttospeech`, i get this error:

> ImportError: No module named grpc._cython.cygrpc

To fix this, I add the following to the `libraries` section of app.yaml:

```
- name: grpcio
  version: latest
```

I then get this error:

```
from six.moves import http_client 
ImportError: No module named moves
```

I try to fix it similarly, but the error persists

```
- name: six
  version: latest
```

[Other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188151/importerror-no-module-named-moves) didn't help.  `six` 1.12.0 is installed in ./lib, and 1.11.0 comes with the latest `gcloud` cloud SDK (233.0.0).

How can I use text-to-speech with Cloud Endpoints?  Even if i get this working, can I expect it to work with GCS and Datastore?  So far, using Flask-RESTful under GAE seems easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These client libraries do not work with the first-generation Python 2.7 runtime, and there are no plans to support them.](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/1893#issuecomment-412963207)

You will need to use the new second-generation Python 3.7 runtime instead, which will let you install arbitrary dependencies. See "[Python 3 Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime)" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that Google Cloud Client Libraries aren't yet compatible with Google App Engine.  The problem I had here persisted when trying to use Text To Speech in a GAE app even though it worked fine when running little tests locally outside of a GAE app.

This issue can be tracked here:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/1893